# ionic2 prod build from google play store freezes on splashscreen

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have built an ionic 2 app which runs fine if installed directly on a real device using ionic run android or ionic run ios, even ionic serve works just fine.

I have since created a production build and code signed this, everything works on testflight for IOS but as soon as I download the app using google play store as a beta tester it just freezes on the splashscreen.

Is there anyway to debug a signed production app as currently this does not show up in chromes inspect devices console. Or has anyone encountered this same problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that when you add the --prod flag to a build it bundles up all the plugins from config.xml

As I hadnt installed all plugins with the --save flag

e.g.

ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-camera --save

The plugins never found there way into the config.xml

*Note to self always install ionic/cordova plugins with --save to get them into the config.xml for production.